# Yammer Impersonation As A Valid Admin

Tags: yammer

1. I registered an app as a valid admin in my network.
2. I got my token.
3. when i request a list of tokens to impersonation  I receive only my token and not all the tokens (of users in my network).

This is the request I'am making:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json?consumer_key={0}&user_id={1}", CONSUMER_KEY, UserId
```

Where {0} = My Application Client Id,
Where {1} = My UserId (The verified admin user id).
what could i be doing wrong?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

My error was I was registered under

> "xxx.com"

and when I requested the token I was under the domain of:

> "yyy.com"

so the token I received was not the right token.

Another mistake I made was trying to impersonate verified admins - a verified admin can't impersonate another verified admin.

**

- Solution:

  1. Register a new app with a user that is registered on the right domain.
  2. Get the token with thee user that is registered on the right domain.
  3. Get id's of users that are not verified admin.

**

Thanks for all your help.

Hope this info contribute to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in user_id the sender_id from the post object

```
var config = require('../config');
module.exports = function (sender_id, tk) {
    var params = '?' + 'user_id=' + sender_id + '&consumer_key=' +    config.YAMMER_CONSUMER_KEY + '&access_token=' + tk;
    var url = 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json' + params;
    return url;
};
```

Comment: Didn't really understand your explanation

Comment: in the user_id parameter instead use the verified admin id use the  sender_id to make the inpersonation request

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation

Comment: I'm getting this error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Even though i'am an verfiied admin.

Comment: are you sure, you ara a verified admin?